# Appending a hidden input value to a textarea value?

Tags: forms

So basically what I need to do is append a hidden input value to the text-area without overriding the original texarea value on submit. What am I doing wrong? This is in the template.tpl file.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     if($form_id){
         $sCampaign = $form['submitted']['campaignstring']['#value'];//hidden value
         $sComments = $form['submitted']['Comments']['#value'];//comments textarea
         $sComments = $sCampaign."-".$sComments; // Appending them.

    }

}
```

I also tried:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
         if($form_id){
             $form['#submit'][] = 'submit_string';
           }
    }

function submit_string($form, &$form_state){    
    $sCampaign = $form['submitted']['campaignstring']['#value'];
    $sComments = $form['submitted']['Comments']['#value'];
    $sComments = $sCampaign."-".$sComments;

}
```

Newer try:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
//Appending Campaign String to comments
$form['submitted']['Comments']['#value'] = array('#value' => $form['submitted']['Comments']['#default_value'] .'/'. $form['submitted']['campaignstring']['#value'],
                );
}


function submitHandler($form, &$form_state){
    $campaingString = $form_state['values']['campaignstring'];
    $comments = $form_state['values']['Comments'];
    $comments = $comments."/////".$campaingString;


    drupal_set_message('Submitted');
    drupal_set_message($form_state['values']);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `$form_state['values']` on submit?

Comment: Would you give me an example? I am a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: You should use `$form_state['values']` array to get submitted values.. You can find more information in this page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little example (Additional information):

```
function my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#title' > 'Name',
    '#type' => 'textfield'
  );

  $form['sec_name'] = array(
    '#title' > 'last name',
    '#type' => 'textfield'
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' > 'Run',
    '#type' => 'submit'
  );

  return $form;
}

function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $f_name = $form_state['values']['name'];
  $s_name = $form_state['values']['sec_name'];

  drupal_set_message('Hello ' . $f_name . ' ' . $s_name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this right now. Will this work in my template.tpl or does it need to be in a module?

Comment: @Django My example is just explanation of `$form_state['values']`, but If you are using `hook_form_alter`, it works in both module files and template.php. My example is only PHP function, and it works everywhere:)

Comment: Any suggestions on why $form_state['values'] is empty after I submit.

Comment: @Django Can you show your code?

Comment: Okay, Added it to the original post

Comment: @Django 1. What is `['#value']`? Is it value of 'value' type element? 2. Put `print_r($form_state)` in submit callback (better install Devel module and use its dpm() function), and check what is being returned in `values` element.

Comment: @Django And `$form['submitted']['Comments']['#value'] = array('#value' => $form['submitted']['Comments']['#default_value'] .'/'. $form['submitted']['campaignstring']['#value'])` is not very clear to me.. Are you assigning array value to `value` element?

Comment: Im just trying to append the hidden field ($form['submitted']['campaignstring']['#value']) value to the Comments field($form['submitted']['Comments']['#value']) while not losing the original comments value if there is one.

Comment: @Django you can't get submitted value in form generation step with $form array, as you are trying.. Because there can not be submitted value in generation step.. You can alter form, add you hidden value or whatever you want, but get submitted value only in submit callback with `$form_state['values']` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
function submit_string($form, &$form_state){    
    $sCampaign = $form_state['values']['campaignstring'];
    $sComments = $form_state['values']['Comments'];
    $sComments = $sCampaign."-".$sComments;
}
```

Your `hook_form_alter()` won't work the way you expect it to work. You need to test if the given $form_id equals the form_id of the form that you want to alter. For example:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "MY_FORM_ID"){
        $form['#submit'][] = 'submit_string';
    }
}
```

You could also use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` like this:

```
hook_form_MY_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'submit_string';
}
```

Find out more here: [Forms API - Modify Forms with hook_form_alter()](https://drupal.org/node/1702628)

Comment: I actually do have it set the way you suggested. I just made it basic because I wanted to cover all forms eventually.